# Perl - open with relative path Apache

Tags: apache, perl

We recently inherited a somewhat legacy perl application and we're working to migrate to a new server as well as setup a sandbox environment so we can start sorting the application out. The issue we're having is the code currently uses some relative paths for the `open` method. And currently works in their shared hosting environment (we have little access to)

```
open(HANDLE,"<../relative/path/to/file.txt")
```

We pulled all of the code, paths, etc. over and for the most part have the application up and running until we run into one of the scripts that does the above, opens a file with a relative path. Then it fails.

If we run the code via the command line, the relative paths work. If we modify the path to be the full path it works both via command line and through Apache (navigating to the page in the browser).

This makes me think there is some module or configuration option we need to set in Apache to allow for the perl scripts to access or use the `open` command with relative paths?

Comment: What error does it throw? Isn't it a permission issue rather than wrong path?

Comment: It does not appear to be a permission issue (did 777 the file at one point) as this works if we use the full path to the file and not the relative path.

We're getting a 'no such file or directory' despite the fact that I can exit vi in the path I'm in and cat the file in question.

The same appears to happen if I move the file into the directory with the script and just try to access it via ./file.txt. Still not seeing the file.

Comment: Another quick note is that the relative paths do work if we run the script via the command line... perl script.pl. This seems to be an issue with only accessing the script via a request through Apache.

Comment: One more tidbit. I'm now having the perl script print `pwd`; and its showing that the current directory as being '/' despite it being /srv/www/site/scripts/script.pl. Not sure why the script would think its cwd is '/' when access the file via http://example.com/scripts/script.pl. Thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: Maybe Apache runs in a `chroot` jail?

Comment: Unless its on by default I do not see mod_chroot loaded nor configured anywhere in any of the apache modules. Do you know how we could verify this and/or disable it? If I also include a print `ls -l` in the same script. I see all of the files/directories at the root level of the server. I would not expect that if the script was jailed to its own directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above. Our final solution was to use:

```
File::Basename qw( dirname ); 
chdir(dirname($0));
```

This allowed us to get the code working while also kept additional code modifications to a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths are relative to the process's current work directory, which is not necessarily the same as a the directory containing the program. It fact, it's often `/` for daemons (and thus their children).

For paths relative to the program's location, use

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

my $qfn = "$RealBin/relative/path/to/file.txt";
open(my $HANDLE, "<", $qfn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess that is the curiosity here. We've pulled over the legacy code that is using the relative path as shown above. However, on the new server the script shows the path as '/'. Instead of modifying the code, how might we be able to set our environment up such that the script sees its path correctly? Our current fix is just adding in use File::Basename qw( dirname );
chdir(dirname($0));

Answer (score 0):

I was running a script out of cgi-bin and wanted to open a template in htdocs/templates so I did this in my script...

```
# open the html template
my $filename = sprintf("%s/templates/test.tmplt", $ENV{DOCUMENT_ROOT});
my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => $filename);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is bad practice to specify file's path in **open** with a fixed string unless the path is predefined and never change - as for example with **/etc/fstab** in linux.

You should change the code to use variable(s) instead.

Define variable at the top of the script -- in feature if you need to change *base* and *path* you will know that you find it at the few first lines of the code.

In such situation add temporary in the code something as

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $fh, '>', 'my_uniq_file.txt')
    or die 'Couldn\'t open my_uniq_file.txt';

print $fh 'This directory is default base for path location';

close $fh;
```

Once you run your script from webserver you should look for the file **my_uniq_tile.txt** -- it's location will be default *base* of web server for the file(s) location.

Now adjust variables with file path accordingly.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir_project = './project_1/';
my $audio_data = 'audio_data.dat';
my $video_data = 'video_data.dat';
my $descr_data = 'descr_data.dat';

my $qfn = $dir_project . $audio_data;

open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
    or die "Couldn't open $qfn";

while( <$fh> ) {
     chomp;
    [do something with data]
}

close $fh;
```

Comment: Thanks. Yea we aren't actually using the fixed path but instead variables as you mention. The path provided in the example is just that for the example. The issue isn't with the path being constructed correctly it has to do with the relative path not working. In your case using a './' is also relative and in our case also fails.